# accessing data out of socket block

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am doing the client-server application vie net module. Client send me data, depending upon the type of data i have to send back response from server. I am doing via socket.on() method. Problem is when i receive data from client i convert it to string to check what has the client sent. Depending upon it i set the array and then want to pass back to client server in json form. The problem is when i set the array in the block the data in it isn't available. It shows me empty array.Below is my code snippet:

```
  var server = net.createServer(
function(socket){
    console.log("Client connection...");

    socket.on('end', function(){
        console.log("Client disconnected...");
    });

    // process data from client
    socket.on('data', function(data){
        //console.log(" Received:", data.toString());
        a=data.toString();
        //console.log(a);
        if(a=="lookupByLastName('Smith')") 
        {
            arr= employees.lookupByLastName('Smith');
            flag=true;
            console.log("hey" +arr.length);
        }

        console.log("check1:"+arr.length+":"+flag); // here array has data

    });

    console.log("check2:"+arr.length+":"+flag); // array length has no data
    // send data to client
    socket.write("Data"+JSON.stringify(arr); ); // arr contains no data

});
```

Comment: You should really read about callbacks in javascript. Your arr object is out of scope. Put it inside the `socket.on()` callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you call `socket.write` on initialization, i.e. when data may not have been received. You should call `socket.write` after you get the data. See modified code below:

```
var server = net.createServer(
function(socket){
    console.log("Client connection...");

    socket.on('end', function(){
        console.log("Client disconnected...");
    });

    // process data from client
    socket.on('data', function(data){
        //console.log(" Received:", data.toString());
        a=data.toString();
        //console.log(a);
        if(a=="lookupByLastName('Smith')") 
        {
            arr= employees.lookupByLastName('Smith');
            flag=true;
            console.log("hey" +arr.length);

            socket.write("Data"+JSON.stringify(arr); ); // Here the array will have the data
        }

        console.log("check1:"+arr.length+":"+flag); // here array has data
    });

});
```